# list型のplotについて

Tags: python, matplotlib, csv

pythonを用いてcsvファイルをlist型として読み込み、pylabでplotしようと思ったら下のような結果となってしまいました(１枚目元のデータ、２枚目plot結果）

[image: 元]
[image: 結果]

プログラムは下の様に記述しました

```
from matplotlib import pylab as pl
import csv

if __name__ == "__main__":

 data = []
 with open("data.csv","r") as f:
     reader = csv.reader(f)
     for row in reader:
      data.append(row[0])

fig = pl.figure()
fig.add_subplot(111)
pl.plot(data)
pl.xlim([0, len(data)])
pl.show()
```

何が原因で元のファイルと同じように表示されないのかわかりません
軸をyticksやylimで整えようとしたのですが何をやってもこの形になってしまいました
ご助言よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSV ファイルの形式がどうなっているか知りませんが、以下でできると思います

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

if __name__ == "__main__":
    data = pd.read_csv("data.csv", names=["x", "y"])

    # print(data) # デバッグ用
    plt.plot(data["x"], data["y"])
    plt.show()
```

追記です
もしうまくいかないようでしたら、CSV ファイルの中身をコメントで頂けたらなんとかできると思います（最初の数行だけでかまいません）

Comment: 返信遅れて申し訳ないです。回答ありがとうございます。教えていただいた方法でやってみた結果、このような結果になってしまいました。https://imgur.com/a/Clhn0hH　また、csvファイルの中身は　https://imgur.com/a/Clhn0hH こんな感じになっています。

Comment: 文字列のデータとなっていたため、floatを用いて数値データにしたらうまく表示できました！ありがとうございました。